# Websphere 8.5.5 Installation: What packages do we need?

Tags: websphere-8, websphere

I need to install on aws instance Websphere 8.5.5 from scratch.
According to some doc i need the following packages:

- Installation Manager
- WebSphere Application Server
- Webserver
- Webserver plugin

Currently i have IBM user that have the rights to download this, but i can't figure which package is which.

I have downloaded:

- Installation Manager 1.9
- 8.5.5-WS-WAS-FP016-part1.zip 8.5.5-WS-WAS-FP016-part2.zip 8.5.5-WS-WAS-FP016-part3.zip
- WAS_V8.5.5_SUPPL_1_OF_3.zip WAS_V8.5.5_SUPPL_2_OF_3.zip WAS_V8.5.5_SUPPL_3_OF_3.zip

Is there additional packages that i need for "imcl" deployments?
If possible could you provide the links for needed packages.

Comment: You downloaded only fix packs. You have to login to Passport Advantage https://www.ibm.com/software/passportadvantage/pao_customer.html  to get WebSphere AppServer binaries.

Comment: Hi @Gas, many thanks for reply. Can you give me the names of packages that are needed or What exactly is needed to start?

Answer (score 1):

After installing IM, according to the IBM KnowledgeCenter topic https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.installation.base.doc/ae/cins_repositories.html, point IM to these install repos:

IBM WebSphere Application Server    http://www.ibm.com/software/repositorymanager/com.ibm.websphere.BASE.v85

IBM HTTP Server for WebSphere Application Server    http://www.ibm.com/software/repositorymanager/com.ibm.websphere.IHS.v85

Web Server Plug-ins for IBM WebSphere Application Server    http://www.ibm.com/software/repositorymanager/com.ibm.websphere.PLG.v85